# Current time and date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I have added the current date and time to my DB using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

However when i echo this date/time it shows in the following format

> 2013-10-04 13:53:47

Is there a way to change this format to

> 04-10-2013 13:53

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the `Date_format` function, documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format. Also, please put more research effort before asking a question, this can be easily googled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way the date is displayed with [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2,
       date_format(date_column, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i') as formatted_date,
       othercolumn
from blogposts
```

Comment: sorry i do not understand? would this go in the db or in my page?

Comment: Put it in your select statement to get the correct date format of the content of your date columns directly from the DB.

Comment: Thanks, this is my select statment `mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX-b", $con)or die( "Unable to select database line 873");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogposts  ")or die('You need enter a catagory ' );` so where exactly would this go? Sorry!!

Comment: replace the `*` with actual column names. One of that is the formatted date column. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however i have added the below code and now have no date showing? `$result=mysql_query("SELECT 
                           title, 
                           content,
                           author,
                           category,
                           image,
                           ID,
                           date_format(created, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%i') as formatted_date,
                           author FROM blogposts  ")
                           or die('You need enter a catagory ' );`

Comment: That is the DB query that gets the data. After that you have to iterate over the results and display the data.

Comment: Can you explain how i do that? Sorry again

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Looks like you need to take a PHP tutorial first. Take the time to learn the basics. If you get stuck, come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, you can select your date wrapped in DATE_FORMAT(date,format).

More information here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try [strf_time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). If it doesn't work you could always [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%d-%m-%Y %T')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$datefromDB;
$dateyourequired = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($datefromDB));
echo $dateyourequired;
?>
```